# Progressive Web Application does not work after clearing cache using @nuxt/pwa

Tags: progressive-web-apps, nuxt.js

I created a `nuxtjs` project with `ssr` mode and `@nuxtjs/pwa` module. It did not update cached files. Then i cleared chromes cache by hitting `inspect > Application tab > Clear Storage in sidebar > clear site data  button`.

[image: clear site data button]

After clearing cache storage Service worker does not work any more. I am using `@nuxtjs/pwa` version `3.0.0-beta.16` and nuxt `2.0.0`.

Service worker status is activated and running but when i set `offline` mode in chrome inspect, does not show anything. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: When you press "Clear site data", your service worker is gone as expected. It will not return until you totally refresh the page and retrieve it again from your backend.

Comment: how can i do this? i mean how to refresh page and retrieve it from backend?

Comment: If you have the dev tools in chrome open, RIGHT click or long click on the browser reload icon - select "Empty cache and hard reload"

Comment: did not work. still not working offline

Comment: If you press the "Clear site data" button while offline, you cannot reload your site until online again.

Comment: i have reloaded page online like you said, then set offline mode service worker does not work

Comment: I'm not sure what is not working for you. You are wiping out your site whenever you press on that button, so it will ALWAYS not work after you press that button. Perhaps you are trying to test something? If so, perhaps you want to uncheck the items under that button to not delete everything form your site.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered something similar.  I did a "Cmd" + "Shift" + "Backspace" (i.e. clear browser cache) and it worked.  I use Firefox, not Chrome, but I think the shortcut is the same.  Bottom line is clearing the actual browser data worked.  You can also try it in Incognito...should have the same effect.